# lm-sensors not recognized my laptop hardware fan

Tags: hardware, fan, temperature, sensors

I have Hp Pavilion dv6 3031-et notebook ; I was install ubuntu this version 4 weeks ago everything fine my video card,sound,battery,etc fine but I have wanna check my fan speed result is  ;

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +68.0°C                                    

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +67.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0002
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 2:      +64.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

lspci ; result ;

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Redwood [Radeon HD 5600 Series]
01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Redwood HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5600 Series]
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
7f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
7f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
7f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
7    f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
7f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
7f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

What am I have to do for this sensors result I wanna all temparature and fan speed

Thank you

Comment: There might not even be the right software to do this. I've got an acer laptop where I'm unable to see more than you do hope the answer from falstaff will do the trick for you. Don't forget to check again after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `sensors_detect` first, it checks your hardware and loads appropriate modules. execute the command `sensors` again then.

Comment: I was do another idea ?

Comment: It's getting complicated then. Try to find out which module was responsibly in your previous Version. Look through dmesg if something is getting disabled for a reason. (I remember I had success once with an additional kernel parameter which forced that module...)

Comment: Well I was try this too but same result still I double check and I add my module I check again I check my hardware also I was look for my graphical card drivers for fan control and everything is fine on windows but I try again my linux thats still same and I was this acpi force code on grub I know that paramters and module

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get irrelevant data for my system including some information for fan(s) with `sudo modprobe w83627ehf-isa-fff8`.

Run this,

> sudo modprobe w83627ehf-isa-fff8

Run `sudo sensors-detect` again

It may help in your case. I hope you can see something real.

[Details about my situation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436526/my-fan-is-not-working-no-active-cooling-system)