# My fan is not working, no active cooling system

Tags: overheating, bios, fan, temperature, sensors

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and my fan is not working(with Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 13.10 it was the same).

> **Short summary of my system**
>
> Quanta TWH motherboard, Intel® Core™ i7-2630QM CPU

### **I follow 3 different ways to solve my problem**

### 1. Using `lm-sensors`, `pwmconfig` and `fancontrol` to control the speed of my fan

First, I try to see what was happening with `lm-sensors`, I even could not detect my fan. Later on, forced with `modeprobe` [Ref1](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.sensors/17253) with following command line.

> sudo modprobe w83627ehf-isa-fff8

It helps to get more sensors with `lm-sensors-detect` but they all in ALARM, I believe they are set as null because I create them artificially or not(I am not sure about what is `modeprobe` is doing for me)?

Here is my `sudo sensors` results after that process.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +61.0 C  (crit = +101.0 C)

w83627ehf-isa-fff8
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:        +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
in1:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
AVCC:         +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
+3.3V:        +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in4:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
in5:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
in6:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +4.08 V  (min =  +4.08 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in9:          +2.04 V  (min =  +2.04 V, max =  +2.04 V)  ALARM
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
temp1:         -1.0 C  (high =  -1.0 C, hyst =  -1.0 C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
temp2:         +0.0 C  (high =  +0.0 C, hyst =  +0.0 C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
temp3:         +0.0 C  (high =  +0.0 C, hyst =  +0.0 C)  ALARM  sensor = CPU diode
cpu0_vid:    +1.219 V
intrusion0:  ALARM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +61.0 C  (high = +86.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 0:         +57.0 C  (high = +86.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 1:         +61.0 C  (high = +86.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 2:         +57.0 C  (high = +86.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
Core 3:         +57.0 C  (high = +86.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +61.0 C
```

At that point, I try to run `sudo pwmconfig`. Still, I am not able go further from `There are no usable PWM outputs.` I stack here with this way. (My computer is not Dell)

### 2. Install the latest microcode for my processor

I instal the following the steps given [here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/microcode), thanks to @floppy for the advise.

> Installing `intel-microcode` and `microcode.ctl` packages (as @floppy suggested) are help to wake up my fan, it helps to decrease CPU temperature. Fan was working quite independent from CPU temperature. It was doing some work but still not efficient at all.
>
> Furthermore, `sensors-detect` is still not able to get my fan without that  `sudo modprobe w83627ehf-isa-fff8`

### 3. BIOS Update

Okey my CPU temperature is lower, but still not enough to perform even for the basic applications.

I also think about to update my BIOS, but I could not convince myself it might be the reason of my problem *in the beginning*. I have QUANTA TWH motherbord with i7-2630qm with INSYDE QR133 BIOS. I update it with USB up-to the QR192.

> BIOS update decreases my CPU temperatures around 10~15 Celcius, I do not know how and why.

**I am still looking for alternative methods to control my fan, or/and force it to work at given/at the maximum rate all the time**

Comment: What are you asking?  If the fan is broke, then fix it.

Comment: My fan is working, I have the dual boot and in Windows everything is OK.

Comment: Then what are you asking?  Why you can't read the speed in Linux?

Comment: Sorry may be this confusion because of my bad selection on words, fan was working physically but was not responding any CPU temperature under Linux control(0 rpm). Thanks to the `@floppy's` advise fan is alive now but it is still not detected by  `lm-sensors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the latest microcode for your processor. According to some linux gurus  **you may be able to improve the functioning of the central processor (CPU) in your computer by applying the latest Intel or AMD microcode. This will improve the functioning of your CPU, because it corrects bugs in the default microcode that it receives from the motherboard**.

Visit [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/microcode) to learn how to install the microcode package for your CPU. Basically, you have to open Synaptic, and search for **intel-microcode** and **microcode.ctl** packages. I hope I am not wrong, and your CPU is from Intel. Amd CPUs can also benefit from this microcode package but it has a different name, **amd64-microcode**.

Maybe after you install intel microcode, and restart you computer your fan will come to live again.

Comment: I install it, my fan is alive again but still lm-sensors not able to detect pwm utilities. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Wow, it really worked. I can't say I am not a little bit surprised. I have a Dell Optiplex machine, older generation, and I don't think intel microcode makes a lot of difference for my computer but from what I've read about this microcode package is that it is mostly targeted for newest computers, desktops and laptops alike, with latest CPUs and so on. Don't forget to check my answer as the one you accepted so i can get the 'gold' they give you in here for each useful answer.

Comment: Yes, it is nice but still I am not able to detect my fan with `sensors-detect`, and so there is no pwm control chance.

Comment: Can this link be of any help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed   You should not limit your search for a solution to Ubuntu forums only, try a wider search, I mean use 'Linux sensors-detect' for a search. And you should also go to your manufacturer page to see if they have support for Linux, and maybe download some of their tools.

Comment: Look, another useful link, I hope, it also says something about installing a graphical interface for checking up on our hardware **sudo apt-get install sensors-applet** . This is the link: http://techthrob.com/2009/03/enabling-hardware-sensors-in-linux/

Comment: Thanks @floppy I already know them, and the first link is clearly talking about `This functionality depends on both your hardware and software`. I was trying, but possibly `pwmconfig` features are not available for me. I update my BIOS, it decrease my CPU temperatures around 10~15 Celcius, I will improve my question with my solutions recommendation. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Man, I am glad I don't have a fancy computer! A lot of issues with all these new CPUs and motherboards and sensors ... I hope you get better performance for power management when using Windows. Have you tried Linux Mint, do you experience the same problems like you do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I followed the instructions for my AMD processor, but it wants to remove `linux-firmware`, `linux-generic` and `linux-image-generic`. Is the computer still usable without these packages?

Comment: Fix your kernel issues first. It seems like you upgraded the kernel partially or there is something wrong with your kernel. Leave microcode package be for the moment and try to repair your system first.

Comment: Fixed fan issue with overheating Acer 7720 laptop with this procedure. Rebooted and fan now runs.