# Ubuntu- notebook overheating fan1 = 0 RPM speed

Tags: 14.04, overheating, fan, fancontrol

I have installed Ubuntu alongisde with Windows 8.1 but my notebook is really loud and temperatures as super high while I'm just browsing webpages on the internet.

Now basically when I do not do anything it's :

```
temp 1: 68-71 min:54 max : All of them 85
physical id: 68-71 min:54
core 0: 67 min:52
core 1: 68-69 min:51
core 2: 70 min:53
core 3: 64 min:52
temp1 : 60 min:52
```

Laptop is really warm and especially loud, I do not have the same problem in Windows even though termeratures are not optimal. In Windows its around 56-58 all of them + notebook is not laud.
My specs:

- Lenovo ideaPad z50-70
  GTX 980 4gb
- Intel i7 haschwell 4720 Hq
- Ubuntu 14 / Windows 8.1

`tlp-stat -t` shows:

```
CPU temp = 69 [°C]
Fan speed (fan1) = 0 [/min]
```

I noticed in Psensor and also in another application that fan1 is at RPM:0 could this be the problem? I'll be thankful for all the help.

Comment: You need to install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score -1):

You might try upgrading to the latest microcode for your processor, as described here: [Link](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/microcode)

Since you have an intel processor, the following command should upgrade the microcode for your cpu:

```
sudo apt-get install microcode.ctl intel-microcode
```

Also, try upgrading your bios to the latest version. This might be tricky, since many manufacturers do only provide Windows executables with the drivers. Since you have Windows installed alongside Ubuntu, use that to run the Bios update. Download the appropriate executables from [Lenovo](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-z-series-laptops/lenovo-z50-70/downloads/ds100528) and run them under Windows.

Comment: I am sorry, i edited my answer to provide all info that is needed.

Comment: This will not fix anything.

Comment: I wonder how you know this, since it fixed the overheating problem of some other guy with a lenovo notebook here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/436526/my-fan-is-not-working-no-active-cooling-system

Comment: Overheating can't be fixed by CPU microcode. And it is obvious why OP has overheating. A new GPU without drivers.

Comment: No but the CPU might produce a little less heat, and the bios update might help with the fan not working? Lets wait for the OP to find out what fixes it.